# React Native Router Flux crashes app when menu/drawer is opened ONLY after build is put on play store

Tags: react-native, google-play, react-native-router-flux

I have finally got my app onto the play store and put it onto the internal test track and in checking it out I find that when I swing out the RNRF menu my app crashes. I cannot replicate this locally even with --variant=release and have not seen this behavior before, problems with RNRF have manifested as problems during build typically not during use.

I have no idea how to debug this problem, I've read that proguard may have been responsible and so made a build without it but that too crashed once I downloaded it form the play store.

I am using the following versions:
react-native-router-flux "^4.1.0-beta.8",
"react": "16.9.0",
"react-native": "0.61.4",

The drawer that gets rendered is as follows:

```
<Scene type="reset" key="login" type={ActionConst.REPLACE} transitionConfig={()=>({screenInterpolator: StackViewStyleInterpolator.forHorizontal })}>

<Drawer
type="reset"
hideNavBar
key="drawer"
drawer={true}
contentComponent={DrawerContent}
drawerImage={MenuIcon}
drawerWidth={Dimensions.get('window').width}
drawerPosition={'right'}
>

        <Scene key='tabbar' transitionConfig={() => ({ screenInterpolator: StackViewStyleInterpolator.forHorizontal })} >
            <Scene key="replaced" type={ActionConst.REPLACE} component={replaced} title="" titleStyle={styles.centerText} initial />
            <Scene key='replaced' component={replaced} title='replaced' titleStyle={styles.centerText} back={true} backTitle="Back" backButtonImage={newBackIcon} backButtonTextStyle={{ color: colors.white, paddingTop: 3 }} navigationBarTitleImage={{ uri: this.props.icons[constants.ICON_FEELINGS] }} navigationBarTitleImageStyle={styles.navigationBarTitleImageStyle2} />

            <Scene key="replaced" component={replaced} title="" titleStyle={styles.centerText} navigationBarTitleImage={{ uri: this.props.icons[constants.replaced] }} back={true} backTitle="Back" backButtonImage={newBackIcon} backButtonTextStyle={{ color: colors.white, paddingTop: 3 }} navigationBarTitleImageStyle={styles.navigationBarTitleImageStyle2} />

            <Scene key="replaced" component={replaced} title="replaced" titleStyle={styles.centerText} navigationBarTitleImage={{ uri: this.props.icons[constants.replaced] }} back={true} backTitle="Back" backButtonImage={newBackIcon} backButtonTextStyle={{ color: colors.white, paddingTop: 3 }} navigationBarTitleImageStyle={styles.navigationBarTitleImageStyle2} />

            <Scene key="replaced" component={Disclaimer} back={true} backTitle="Back" backButtonImage={newBackIcon} backButtonTextStyle={{ color: colors.white, paddingTop: 3 }} navigationBarTitleImage={{ uri: this.props.icons[constants.replaced] }} navigationBarTitleImageStyle={styles.navigationBarTitleImageStyle2} />

            <Scene key="replaced" component={replaced} title="replaced" titleStyle={styles.centerText} back={true} backTitle="Back" backButtonImage={newBackIcon} backButtonTextStyle={{ color: colors.white, paddingTop: 3 }} navigationBarTitleImage={{ uri: this.props.icons[constants.replaced] }} navigationBarTitleImageStyle={styles.navigationBarTitleImageStyle2} />
            <Scene key="replaced" component={replaced} title="replaced" titleStyle={styles.centerText} back={true} backTitle="Back" backButtonImage={newBackIcon} backButtonTextStyle={{ color: colors.white, paddingTop: 3 }} navigationBarTitleImage={{ uri: this.props.icons[constants.replaced] }} navigationBarTitleImageStyle={styles.navigationBarTitleImageStyle2} />

            <Scene key="replaced" component={replaced} title="replaced" titleStyle={styles.centerText} back={true} backTitle="Back" backButtonImage={newBackIcon} backButtonTextStyle={{ color: colors.white, paddingTop: 3 }} navigationBarTitleImage={{ uri: this.props.icons[constants.replaced] }} navigationBarTitleImageStyle={styles.navigationBarTitleImageStyle2} />
            <Scene key="replaced" component={replaced} title="replaced" titleStyle={styles.centerText} back={true} backTitle="Save" backButtonImage={newBackIcon} backButtonTextStyle={{ color: colors.white, paddingTop: 3 }} navigationBarTitleImage={{ uri: this.props.icons[constants.replaced] }} navigationBarTitleImageStyle={styles.navigationBarTitleImageStyle2} />
            <Scene key="replaced" component={replaced} title={"replaced"} titleStyle={styles.centerText} back={true} backTitle="Back" backButtonImage={newBackIcon} backButtonTextStyle={{ color: colors.white, paddingTop: 3 }} navigationBarTitleImage={{ uri: this.props.icons[constants.replaced] }} navigationBarTitleImageStyle={styles.navigationBarTitleImageStyle2} />
        </Scene>

    </Drawer>
    <Scene key="createAccount" component={CreateAccount} back={true} backTitle="Back" backButtonImage={newBackIcon} backButtonTextStyle={{ color: colors.white, paddingTop: 3 }} />
</Scene>
```

The app will still open up, and I can navigate around it without crashing so long as I do not tap the hamburger menu icon or pull the menu from the right. If I tap the icon it crashes immediately. If I pull from the right it crashes in like a quarter of a second but I am able to see that it is being rendered properly before it crashes.

Any help about the actual problem or how to get more information about debugging it would be greatly appreciated, I really have no idea what my next step is from here since I can't get any feedback about the problem.

Comment: `key` values are supposed to be unique. did you replace all values with `replaced`?

Comment: @kenmistry All the key names were unique, I just changed them to 'replaced' for this post. I don't recall ever finding a satisfying answer to the problem. I believe after tearing everything apart, I created a new project, re-installed everything with the latest versions available, wasted much more time tackling the problems that popped up with that and this particular problem didn't appear after that.